# Windows::toolbar::NM_CUSTOMDRAW. Changing toolbar background color

Tags: c++, winapi, toolbar

here's the excerpt from the code.
Styles of the toolbar before creation:

```
DWORD styles = TBSTYLE_FLAT | WS_CHILD  | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS; //| TBSTYLE_CUSTOMERASE;//| WS_BORDER ;
DWORD cc_styles =  CCS_VERT | CCS_NODIVIDER | CCS_NORESIZE;
```

Handling NM_CUSTOMDRAW:

```
    case WM_NOTIFY:
        switch ( ((LPNMHDR)lparam)->code )
{
...
        case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
        {
            //LPNMHDR header_ptr = safe_ptr_cast< LPNMHDR >( &lparam );
            //if ( header_ptr->hwndFrom == m_ptr->get_operation_tab_toolbar_handle( ) )
            LPNMTBCUSTOMDRAW data_ptr = (LPNMTBCUSTOMDRAW) lparam;
            switch(data_ptr->nmcd.dwDrawStage) 
            {
                case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
                    SetWindowTheme(m_ptr->get_operation_tab_toolbar_handle(), _T(""), _T(""));
                    //data_ptr->hbrMonoDither = GetStockBrush(BLACK_BRUSH);
                    SetBkColor( data_ptr->nmcd.hdc, RGB(0,0,0));
                    FillRect( data_ptr->nmcd.hdc, &data_ptr->nmcd.rc, RGB(0,0,0));
                    //FillRect( data_ptr->nmcd.hdc, &data_ptr->nmcd.rc, GetStockBrush(BLACK_BRUSH));
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                {
                    return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I receive only CDDS_PREPAINT. In the documentation [MSDN Custom Drawing Doc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
it's said that on the returned value CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT should come the next.

Comment: show your call to SetClassLong, because if your not hooking the control aka "Super Classing" it properly (as your post indicates), your message handler code should never be called....

Answer (score 1):

When the toolbar is created using the styles TBSTYLE_FLATE or TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT either TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT it uses the parent background color. Thus, to achieve different background color for a toolbar one should use SetClassLongPtr (for the 32x and 64x compatibility) for a parent window. This way problem is solved.